# Auslassungspunkte, Semikolon, Strichpunkt und Leerzeichen in einer Aufzählung

Tags: punctuation, list, ellipsis

Betrachten wir folgendes Beispiel einer Aufzählung:

> Wir betrachten folgende Darstellungen der natürlichen Zahlen:
>
> - Ordinalzahlen: ∅, {∅}, {∅,{∅}} … ;
> - Dezimalzahlen: 0, 1, 2 … ;
> - römische Zahlen: ‹›, ‹I›, ‹II›, ‹III›, ‹IV› …

Ich konnte keine Regel zur Kombination von Auslassungspunkten mit Semikolon in Aufzählungen finden. Kennt ihr eine? Sieht die Aufzählung oben gut aus?

Answer (score 2):

**Antwort:**

Was die Leerzeichen nach den Kommas betrifft, sind Ihre drei Beispiele korrekt gesetzt. Sogar das fehlende Leerzeichen innerhalb der Menge {∅,{∅}} ist korrekt (siehe Begründung unten). Es fehlt lediglich jeweils ein Komma vor den Auslassungspunkten, auch wenn ich es vereinzelt schon ohne gesehen habe. Wenn Sie die Strichpunkte unbedingt mit Semikolons abschließen wollen – ich würde sie weglassen –, dann müsste das davorstehende Leerzeichen gestrichen werden, also:

> - Ordinalzahlen: ∅, {∅}, {∅,{∅}}, …;
> - Dezimalzahlen: 0, 1, 2, …;
> - römische Zahlen: ‹›, ‹I›, ‹II›, ‹III›, ‹IV›, …

**Begründung betreffs Leerzeichen:**

Bei Ihren Beispielen werden einzelne mathematische Objekte, die jeweils durch Zeichen- oder Symbolketten repräsentiert sind, in Fließtext aufgezählt. Es gelten demnach die gewöhnlichen typografischen Regeln, wie man sie beim Aufzählen von (Teil)Wörtern einer gesprochenen Sprache verwendet.

Anders sieht es aus, wenn wir ein einziges mathematisches Objekt betrachten, bei dem die Aufzählung zur Symbolkette gehört. Häufig werden die Leerzeichen dann weggelassen. (Es gibt Leute, die auch hier explizit Leerzeichen setzen würden.) Ein Beispiel ist die Beschreibung einer Menge durch Aufzählen der Elemente:

> {1,2,3,4,…}

Ein anderes Beispiel ist ein mathematischer Ausdruck:

> ∀ *x* ∈ {0,1,2,*a*,*b*,*c*} : *P*<sub>neu</sub>(*x*)

Das ist zumindest der Standard bei Satzprogrammen wie [LaTeX](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), die zwischen einem (Fließ)Text- und einem Mathe-Modus unterscheiden, und bei denen der Kompiler sich um die Feinheiten der Typografie kümmert. Im Mathe-Modus werden eingegebene Leerzeichen ignoriert, und der Kompiler entscheidet, wie groß die Weißräume zwischen den Symbolen sein sollen. Die Eingabe

> `\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots \}`

erzeugt beispielsweise den Ausdruck für die Menge oben, der keine Leerzeichen enthält. Wer Leerzeichen haben möchte, muss den Kompiler explizit anweisen, sie zu setzen, etwa durch Eingabe der Zeichenkette

> `\{ 1, \, 2, \, 3, \, 4, \, \ldots \}`

Comment: @user49915 Und ich könnte jetzt Seiten verlinken, wo das Komma vor den Auslassungspunkten gesetzt wurde.

Comment: @user49915 Zum Beispiel auf der von Ihnen verlinkten Wikipedia-Seite weiter unten: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslassungspunkte#Verwendung_in_der_Mathematik. Ansonsten diverse Lehrbücher der Mathematik, wie https://books.google.de/books?id=lDu8BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=zahlentheorie&hl=de&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false ...

Comment: ... oder https://books.google.de/books?id=orouh15VgsQC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q&f=false oder https://books.google.de/books?id=frQuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&dq=lineare%20algebra&hl=de&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false oder https://books.google.de/books?id=CQ_wc67PkFQC&lpg=PP1&dq=analysis&hl=de&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false oder https://books.google.de/books?id=vJPGCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA49&dq=folgen%20reihen&hl=de&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false, um mal wahllos ein paar Beispiele herauszugreifen.

Comment: @user49915 Ich muss allerdings gestehen, dass ich auch bei nicht-mathematischen Aufzählungen das Komma setzen würde und mir neu ist, dass die Empfehlung lautet, kein Komma zu setzen (_Äpfel, Birnen, Pflaumen ..._). Für mich hat jede Auf_zählung_ allerdings auch was mit Mathematik zu tun.